# Connect to local socket

Tags: swift, sockets

I've been trying to create a connection to a local socket file, but errno always returns -1

```
var socketPath = "/path/to/socket"

let sockDesc = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0)

var address =  sockaddr_un()
address.sun_family = UInt8(AF_LOCAL)
address.sun_len = UInt8(bitPattern:Int8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_un>.size))

let dataPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(&address.sun_path.0)
strncpy(dataPtr, socketPath, socketPath.characters.count)

let result = withUnsafePointer(to: &address) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {

        connect(sockDesc, $0, socklen_t(MemoryLayout<sockaddr>.stride));
    }
}
```

The socket is valid, as another client, developed in Qt can happily connect to this path.

Is there an obvious mistake here, or should this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third argument of `connect()` must be the actual size
of the `sockaddr_un`, not that of the "generic" `sockaddr`.
With some minor simplifications:

```
let socketPath = "/path/to/socket"

let sockDesc = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
var address = sockaddr_un()
address.sun_family = UInt8(AF_LOCAL)
address.sun_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_un>.size)
strlcpy(&address.sun_path.0, socketPath, MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: address.sun_path))
let socklen = socklen_t(address.sun_len)

let result = withUnsafePointer(to: &address) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
        connect(sockDesc, $0, socklen);
    }
}
```

Note also that

```
strncpy(dataPtr, socketPath, socketPath.characters.count)
```

in your code copies `socketPath.characters.count` bytes to
`dataPtr`, which is wrong for several reasons:

- `socketPath.characters.count` is not the number of UTF-8 bytes
  if the string contains non-ASCII characters,
- it does not guarantee that the destination string is null-terminated,
- it may overwrite the destination buffer.

`strncpy()` is easily misused, and `strlcpy()` (if available) is
often a better choice.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for and great to know about strlcpy too.